# What's the best way to grab the latest 10 pictures from Facebook Page with more than 10,000 likes?

Tags: php, facebook

I need to create a script in PHP that automatically grabs the latest 10 pictures from a Facebook Page (example: https://www.facebook.com/stackoverflowpage) that have more than a specific amount of likes (example: 10,000). I want to run the script every hour to make sure I grab all the pictures with their titles.

I don't think this has ever been done before. What is the best approach to this problem in your opinion?

I think I have three choices:

1. Fetch the data via Facebook Page's HTML Code
2. Fetch the data via Facebook Graph
3. Fetch the data via Facebook API

Comment: Nr 2. Use multi queries.

Comment: @Jack Am I correct that I can get the images + titles with one query?

Comment: @Jack and more importantly, do I need an AUTH token for this?

Comment: Wich pages are you querying? Pages that you are administrator?

Comment: @FabioAntunes I don't administrator the page.

Comment: So how do intend to get the pages that have >10000 fans?

Comment: @FabioAntunes I am talking about a page that posts pictures. Some of these pictures are good (receive more than 10,000 likes) and some not. I want to grab the latest 10 good pictures.

Comment: UPDATE: Alright, it does not seem to be that difficult. I am working on the script right now and it will be finished in a couple of minutes. Will post it an answer for the Future Googlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just finished my script. Here's my solution in PHP:

```
$album_id = "20531316728";
$like_minimum = 5000;


$album_data = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/".$album_id."/photos");
$album_data_array = json_decode($album_data,true);

// loop album
foreach($album_data_array as $item){  
    // loop posts
    foreach($item as $item){ 
        // grab id, source, message
        $photo_id = $item[id];
        $photo_source = $item[source];
        $photo_message = $item[name];

        // count likes
        // facebook doesn't allow us to grab this data. we'll do it anyway.
        $like_data = file_get_contents("http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=".$photo_id);
        $like_count = explode(' others like this.","ranges":', $like_data);
        $like_count = $like_count[0];
        $like_count = explode('and ', $like_count);
        end($like_count);
        $key = key($like_count);
        $like_count = $like_count[$key];
        $like_count = str_replace(",", "", $like_count);
        $like_count = intval($like_count);

        // check if like_minimum reached
        if($like_count>$like_minimum){
            // SUCCESS!

            // Do stuff...
        }
    }
}
```